# Event namespace for multiple child controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, events, namespaces, angularjs-scope

I am trying to namespace events emitted by multiple child controllers of the same type. The problem is letting the parent know the child id. Consider the following scenario.

```
<div ng-controller="Parent">
  <div ng-include="child1"></div>
  <div ng-include="child2"></div>
  ... and so on, the parent decides which templates to include on the fly
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="Child.html">
  <div ng-controller="Child">...</div>
</script>

function Parent($scope) {
  $scope.child1 = "Child.html";
  $scope.child2 = "Child.html";

  // The problem is setting these
  $scope.childId1 = 1;
  $scope.childId2 = 2;

  $scope.on($scope.childId1 + ".someEvent", function() {
    // Handle event from child 1
  });
  $scope.on($scope.childId2 + ".someEvent", function() {
    // Handle event from child 2
  });
} 

function Child($scope) {
  $scope.id = getNewId();

  // Here I would like to do something like
  $parent[someKey] = $scope.id;

  // So that I can emit events like this
  $scope.someEvent = function() {
    $scope.$emit($scope.id + ".someEvent", data);
  }
}
```

So I think the problem has two parts.

1.) How do I pass someKey from the parent to the child.

2.) How do I set someKey on the parent scope from within the child. Would like to avoid using $parent. Not even sure if this variable is available in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Use the messaging to transmit the id you want to use

I would switch your "$on" message in your parent to look like this:

```
$scope.on(".someEvent", function(event,data,id) {
    switch(id) {
        case 1:
            // Handle event from child 1
        case 2:
            // Handle event from child 2
    }

  });
```

And your emit messaging to look like this:

```
$scope.someEvent = function() {
    $scope.$emit(".someEvent", data, $scope.id);
  }
```

Comment: My parent does not know the child id. I want to give each controller a unique id by making a call to a service.

Comment: My solution is in the following fiddle:
   http://jsfiddle.net/lesouthern/5DZGv/

Please elaborate if this is not what you are describing

Comment: The problem with this solution is that $rootScope.$on('childEvent' is a catch all handler. I want to be able to register handler that listen to a specific child only.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my problem by creating a loadController directive. This directive sets a parent key on the child, and this allows me to create handlers for events from a specific child instance only. In my question I tried to set the child id on the parent. I ended up doing it the other way around, i.e. make the parent set an id on the child. So in the parent I would do

```
$scope.$on($scope.id + ".child1.click", function(event, data) {
  $scope.messages.push(data);
});
```

**Where the string "child1" is whatever the parent wants to make it.** And in the child I would emit like this

```
$scope.$emit($scope.key + ".click", data);
```

Notice that

```
$scope.id + ".child1" == $scope.key
```

For a full example see this
http://plnkr.co/edit/2CdzQSKgWODIRvL5OZ9O